# Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID

Tags: c#, json, json.net

It is possible to define a custom "list-merge" startegy used for the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` method?

**Example:**

I have two models:

```
class Parent
{
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

class Child 
{
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

My initial JSON:

```
{  
   "Uuid":"cf82b1fd-1ca0-4125-9ea2-43d1d71c9bed",
   "Name":"John",
   "Childs":[  
      {  
         "Uuid":"96b93f95-9ce9-441d-bfb0-f44b65f7fe0d",
         "Name":"Philip",
         "Score":100
      },
      {  
         "Uuid":"fe7837e0-9960-4c45-b5ab-4e4658c08ccd",
         "Name":"Peter",
         "Score":150
      },
      {  
         "Uuid":"1d2cdba4-9efb-44fc-a2f3-6b86a5291954",
         "Name":"Steve",
         "Score":80
      }
   ]
}
```

and my update JSON:

```
{  
   "Uuid":"cf82b1fd-1ca0-4125-9ea2-43d1d71c9bed",
   "Childs":[  
      {  
         "Uuid":"fe7837e0-9960-4c45-b5ab-4e4658c08ccd",
         "Score":170
      }
   ]
}
```

All I need is to specify a model property (by attribute) used for matching list items (in my case the `Uuid` property of Child), so calling the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` on the object deserialized from my initial JSON with a update JSON (it contains ONLY changed values + Uuids for every object) results to update only list elements contained in the update JSON macthed by Uuid (in my case update a Peter's score) and elements not contained in the update JSON leave without change.

I'm searching for some universal solution - I need to apply it on large JSONs with a lot of nested lists (but every model has some unique property). So I need to recursively call `PopulateObject` on matched list item.

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) that implements the required merge logic.  This is possible because [`JsonConverter.ReadJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) is passed an `existingValue` parameter that contains the pre-existing contents of the property being deserialized.

Thus:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class JsonMergeKeyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

public class KeyedListMergeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly IContractResolver contractResolver;

    public KeyedListMergeConverter(IContractResolver contractResolver)
    {
        if (contractResolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contractResolver");
        this.contractResolver = contractResolver;
    }

    static bool CanConvert(IContractResolver contractResolver, Type objectType, out Type elementType, out JsonProperty keyProperty)
    {
        elementType = objectType.GetListType();
        if (elementType == null)
        {
            keyProperty = null;
            return false;
        }
        var contract = contractResolver.ResolveContract(elementType) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
        {
            keyProperty = null;
            return false;
        }
        keyProperty = contract.Properties.Where(p => p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(JsonMergeKeyAttribute), true).Count > 0).SingleOrDefault();
        return keyProperty != null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Type elementType;
        JsonProperty keyProperty;
        return CanConvert(contractResolver, objectType, out elementType, out keyProperty);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (contractResolver != serializer.ContractResolver)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Inconsistent contract resolvers");
        Type elementType;
        JsonProperty keyProperty;
        if (!CanConvert(contractResolver, objectType, out elementType, out keyProperty))
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid input type {0}", objectType));

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return existingValue;

        var list = existingValue as IList;
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
        {
            list = list ?? (IList)contractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
            serializer.Populate(reader, list);
        }
        else
        {
            var jArray = JArray.Load(reader);
            var comparer = new KeyedListMergeComparer();
            var lookup = jArray.ToLookup(i => i[keyProperty.PropertyName].ToObject(keyProperty.PropertyType, serializer), comparer);
            var done = new HashSet<JToken>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var key = keyProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(item);
                var replacement = lookup[key].Where(v => !done.Contains(v)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (replacement != null)
                {
                    using (var subReader = replacement.CreateReader())
                        serializer.Populate(subReader, item);
                    done.Add(replacement);
                }
            }
            // Populate the NEW items into the list.
            if (done.Count < jArray.Count)
                foreach (var item in jArray.Where(i => !done.Contains(i)))
                {
                    list.Add(item.ToObject(elementType, serializer));
                }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    class KeyedListMergeComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
    {
        #region IEqualityComparer<object> Members

        bool IEqualityComparer<object>.Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            else if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<object>.GetHashCode(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static Type GetListType(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genType == typeof(List<>))
                    return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Notice that the converter needs to know the [`IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) currently in use.  Having it makes finding the key parameter easier, and also ensures that, if the key parameter has a `[JsonProperty(name)]` attribute, the replacement name is respected.

Then add the attribute:

```
class Child
{
    [JsonMergeKey]
    [JsonProperty("Uuid")] // Replacement name for testing
    public Guid UUID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

And use the converter as follows:

```
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
        var converter = new KeyedListMergeConverter(serializer.ContractResolver);
        serializer.Converters.Add(converter);

        using (var reader = new StringReader(updateJson))
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, parent);
        }
```

The converter assumes that the key parameter is always present in the JSON.  Also, if any entries in the JSON being merged have keys that are not found in the existing list, they are appended to the list.

**Update**

The original converter is specifically hardcoded for [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and takes advantage of the fact that `List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IList`.  If your collection is not a `List<T>` but still implements `IList<T>`, the following should work:

```
public class KeyedIListMergeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly IContractResolver contractResolver;

    public KeyedIListMergeConverter(IContractResolver contractResolver)
    {
        if (contractResolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contractResolver");
        this.contractResolver = contractResolver;
    }

    static bool CanConvert(IContractResolver contractResolver, Type objectType, out Type elementType, out JsonProperty keyProperty)
    {
        if (objectType.IsArray)
        {
            // Not implemented for arrays, since they cannot be resized.
            elementType = null;
            keyProperty = null;
            return false;
        }
        var elementTypes = objectType.GetIListItemTypes().ToList();
        if (elementTypes.Count != 1)
        {
            elementType = null;
            keyProperty = null;
            return false;
        }
        elementType = elementTypes[0];
        var contract = contractResolver.ResolveContract(elementType) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
        {
            keyProperty = null;
            return false;
        }
        keyProperty = contract.Properties.Where(p => p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(JsonMergeKeyAttribute), true).Count > 0).SingleOrDefault();
        return keyProperty != null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Type elementType;
        JsonProperty keyProperty;
        return CanConvert(contractResolver, objectType, out elementType, out keyProperty);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (contractResolver != serializer.ContractResolver)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Inconsistent contract resolvers");
        Type elementType;
        JsonProperty keyProperty;
        if (!CanConvert(contractResolver, objectType, out elementType, out keyProperty))
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid input type {0}", objectType));

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return existingValue;

        var method = GetType().GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
        try
        {
            return genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer, keyProperty });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializationException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("ReadJsonGeneric<T> error", ex);
        }
    }

    object ReadJsonGeneric<T>(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer, JsonProperty keyProperty)
    {
        var list = existingValue as IList<T>;
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
        {
            list = list ?? (IList<T>)contractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
            serializer.Populate(reader, list);
        }
        else
        {
            var jArray = JArray.Load(reader);
            var comparer = new KeyedListMergeComparer();
            var lookup = jArray.ToLookup(i => i[keyProperty.PropertyName].ToObject(keyProperty.PropertyType, serializer), comparer);
            var done = new HashSet<JToken>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var key = keyProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(item);
                var replacement = lookup[key].Where(v => !done.Contains(v)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (replacement != null)
                {
                    using (var subReader = replacement.CreateReader())
                        serializer.Populate(subReader, item);
                    done.Add(replacement);
                }
            }
            // Populate the NEW items into the list.
            if (done.Count < jArray.Count)
                foreach (var item in jArray.Where(i => !done.Contains(i)))
                {
                    list.Add(item.ToObject<T>(serializer));
                }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    class KeyedListMergeComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
    {
        #region IEqualityComparer<object> Members

        bool IEqualityComparer<object>.Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            return object.Equals(x, y);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<object>.GetHashCode(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetIListItemTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that merging is not implemented for arrays since they are not resizable.

Comment: I was hoping this was the solution to a similar issue I was having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839939/deserializing-objects-stored-in-json-using-a-custom-idefaultcontractresolver-res but even using this and setting the name as a merge key stil results in the data populating incorectly