# Populating & merging an object collection from Json using a custom iDefaultContractResolver results in shifted/corrupt data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is my class data structure that I am serializing/deserializing:

```
public class SettingGroup
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool visible { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SettingGroup> groups { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Setting> settings { get; set; }
    public SettingGroup()
    {
        groups = new ObservableCollection<SettingGroup>();
        settings = new ObservableCollection<Setting>();
        visible = true;
    }
}

public class Setting
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool visible { get; set; }
    public DescriptionVisibility descriptionVisibility { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> configuration { get; set; }
    public dynamic settingValue { get; set; }
    public SettingType settingType { get; set; }
    public SettingControl settingControl { get; set; }
    public Setting()
    {
        visible = true;
        configuration = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    }
}
```

I am using the following to ensure that only the setting names and values are stored in the JSON, the rest are structured within the application itself and do not need to be saved/loaded via JSON;

```
    private static string safeFileName(string fileName)
    {
        string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + " ";
        Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));
        fileName = r.Replace(fileName, "");
        return fileName;
    }
    public static void saveSettings(this SettingGroup settingGroup, string fileName = "")
    {
        var jsonResolver = new IgnorableSerializerContractResolver();

        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(SettingGroup), "visible");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(SettingGroup), "description");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "visible");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "descriptionVisibility");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "configuration");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "settingType");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "settingControl");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "description");


        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, ContractResolver = jsonResolver };

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            fileName = safeFileName(settingGroup.name);

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Global.DataDirectory)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Global.DataDirectory);
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Global.DataDirectory, fileName+".json"), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settingGroup, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings));
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public static void loadSettings(this SettingGroup settingGroup, string fileName = "")
    {
        var jsonResolver = new IgnorableSerializerContractResolver();

        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(SettingGroup), "visible");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(SettingGroup), "description");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "visible");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "descriptionVisibility");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "configuration");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "settingType");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "settingControl");
        jsonResolver.Ignore(typeof(Setting), "description");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            fileName = safeFileName(settingGroup.name);

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Global.DataDirectory)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Global.DataDirectory);
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto, ContractResolver = jsonResolver };
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Global.DataDirectory, fileName + ".json")), settingGroup, serializerSettings);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The custom iDefaultContractResolver is one that I have seen floating around SE but will include here anyway for completeness:

```
public class IgnorableSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> Ignores;

    public IgnorableSerializerContractResolver()
    {
        this.Ignores = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
    }

    public void Ignore(Type type, params string[] propertyName)
    {
        if (!this.Ignores.ContainsKey(type)) this.Ignores[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in propertyName)
        {
            this.Ignores[type].Add(prop);
        }
    }

    public bool IsIgnored(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        if (!this.Ignores.ContainsKey(type)) return false;

        // if no properties provided, ignore the type entirely
        if (this.Ignores[type].Count == 0) return true;

        return this.Ignores[type].Contains(propertyName);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (this.IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName)
        // need to check basetype as well for EF -- @per comment by user576838
        || this.IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType.BaseType, property.PropertyName))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => { return false; };
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

It saves just fine just as I would expect with only the properties that I want to save, but loading causes the data to be "shifted", all the setting values will load into the wrong settings and such and cause type mismatches when trying to access them. I have tried with and without the custom Json Settings in the load portion with no difference in behavior. Also worth noting that without the iDefaultContractResolver the entire structure saves/loads just fine, but id rather not clutter my JSON files with unneeded data.

Here are the settings classes being constructed and populated with sample data:

```
        SettingGroup Settings = new SettingGroup();
        Settings.name = "Application Settings";
        Settings.description = "Common application settings.";

        SettingGroup generalSettings = new SettingGroup();
        generalSettings.name = "General settings";
        Settings.groups.Add(generalSettings);

        SettingGroup themeSettings = new SettingGroup();
        themeSettings.name = "Theme settings";
        Settings.groups.Add(themeSettings);

        SettingGroup updateSettings = new SettingGroup();
        updateSettings.name = "Update settings";
        Settings.groups.Add(updateSettings);

        SettingGroup startupSettings = new SettingGroup();
        startupSettings.name = "Startup settings";
        generalSettings.groups.Add(startupSettings);

        Setting startWithWindows = new Setting();
        startWithWindows.name = "Start IM with Windows";
        startWithWindows.settingValue = true;
        startWithWindows.settingControl = SettingControl.Checkbox;
        startupSettings.settings.Add(startWithWindows);

        Setting startMinimized = new Setting();
        startMinimized.name = "Start IM minimized";
        startMinimized.settingValue = true;
        startMinimized.settingControl = SettingControl.Checkbox;
        startupSettings.settings.Add(startMinimized);

        SettingGroup performanceSettings = new SettingGroup();
        performanceSettings.name = "Performance settings";
        generalSettings.groups.Add(performanceSettings);

        Setting threadPriority = new Setting();
        threadPriority.name = "Thread priority";
        threadPriority.description = "This setting may not have a noticeible impact on all platforms, especially higer end ones.";
        threadPriority.settingValue = 3;
        threadPriority.settingControl = SettingControl.Slider;
        threadPriority.configuration.Add("lowVal",0);
        threadPriority.configuration.Add("highVal", 7);
        threadPriority.configuration.Add("interval", 1);
        performanceSettings.settings.Add(threadPriority);
```

Edited to include Json sources and results:

Complete Json structure that has the settings info and default values:

```
{
  "name": "Application Settings",
  "description": "Common application settings.",
  "visible": true,
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "General settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Startup settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Start IM with Windows",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "Start IM minimized",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Thread priority",
              "description": "This setting may not have a noticeible impact on all platforms, especially higer end ones.",
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {
                "lowVal": 0,
                "highVal": 7,
                "interval": 1
              },
              "settingValue": 3,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Theme settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Update settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "General settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Startup settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Start IM with Windows",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "Start IM minimized",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Thread priority",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": 3,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Theme settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Update settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

Data that is saved by my saveSettings extension that is designed to save only needed info such as group name children and setting names and value (this looks correct)

```
{
  "name": "Application Settings",
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "General settings",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Startup settings",
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Start IM with Windows",
              "settingValue": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Start IM minimized",
              "settingValue": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance settings",
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Thread priority",
              "settingValue": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Theme settings",
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Update settings",
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

But when loaded and merged with the existing class objects this is what the resulting data looks like, notice the duplicates and invalid values in control type which results in type mismatches IE cannot load a `long` value into a `bool` used by checkbox.

```
{
  "name": "Application Settings",
  "description": "Common application settings.",
  "visible": true,
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "General settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Startup settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Start IM with Windows",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "Start IM minimized",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Thread priority",
              "description": "This setting may not have a noticeible impact on all platforms, especially higer end ones.",
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {
                "lowVal": 0,
                "highVal": 7,
                "interval": 1
              },
              "settingValue": 3,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Theme settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Update settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "General settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "Startup settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Start IM with Windows",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "Start IM minimized",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": true,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Performance settings",
          "description": null,
          "visible": true,
          "groups": [],
          "settings": [
            {
              "name": "Thread priority",
              "description": null,
              "visible": true,
              "descriptionVisibility": 0,
              "configuration": {},
              "settingValue": 3,
              "settingType": 0,
              "settingControl": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Theme settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Update settings",
      "description": null,
      "visible": true,
      "groups": [],
      "settings": []
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that specifying a key for my data may solve my issues? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628916/json-net-populateobject-update-list-elements-based-on-id

Comment: @dbc added some Json dumps to illustrate what is happening with the data notice in the final json data where it is supposed to be the overlay result of the first two, the data actually duplicates and in the second occurrence of `Performance settings` the `settingControl` property is set to 0 all by itself.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Every time I round-trip your `SettingGroup` using your `IgnorableSerializerContractResolver` the result comes back unchanged.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/tR0xY6.  You mention something about "merging", so if you can create a reproducible example of problems with merging, we might be able to help.

Comment: @dbc Im not sure what you are trying to demonstrate there, as I said the settings files saves and looks just as intended, but when it is merged back into the Settings object it creates duplicates in there, since the fiddle as far as I know has no way to pause execution and peer into the Setting object to see the bad data this will not demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You can see in this example https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ti6C2J the merged data is just duplication.

Comment: OK, I see the call to `PopulateObject` now.  Because I don't have your definitions for things like `Global.DataDirectory` I have been trying to reproduce this by reading & writing strings.

Comment: Ive updated my fiddle to show some other code that is "supposed" to merge on a key, in my case the name prop, this also just duplicates everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `KeyedIListMergeConverter` (not the original `KeyedListMergeConverter` which was specifically for merging `List<T>` collections) from [Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628916/json-net-populateobject-update-list-elements-based-on-id), attaching `[JsonMergeKey]` to the names:

```
public class SettingGroup
{
    [JsonMergeKey]
    public string name { get; set; }
    // Remainder unchanged
}

public class Setting
{
    [JsonMergeKey]
    public string name { get; set; }
    // Remainder unchanged
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(Global.DataDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Global.DataDirectory);
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto, ContractResolver = jsonResolver };
        serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new KeyedIListMergeConverter(settings.ContractResolver));
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Global.DataDirectory, fileName + ".json")), settingGroup, serializerSettings);
```

Comment: ahhhhh, first impressions are that this is working splendidly! ill play with it a bit then come back and accept the answer if this is in fact resolved.