# Manipulate List items based on shared id

Tags: c#, json, merge

I want to get value from one List and set in another List item value. For eg -

```
Response.value{[0]=ID : 1
                  Brand : Audi
                  Speed : null
              [1]=ID : 2
                  Brand : Honda
                  Speed : null }
Response1.value{[0]=ID : 1
                  Brand : null
                  Speed : 150
              [1]=ID : 2
                  Brand : null
                  Speed : 140}
```

I would like to take Speed value from Response1 and set it in Response in Speed property based on ID. 
I am getting ID and Brand from one url and ID and Speed from another url using Odata then I had converted the JSon into List. If there is another way that I can concatenate the result based on ID that also would be useful. I will get Brand value for sure but Speed value can be null. So, I would like to add speed values in 1st List as it comes whether its null or value .

Comment: your json object is not in proper format

Comment: Need to see a [mcve] showing your actual model and JSON, but you might be able to use `KeyedIListMergeConverter` from [Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638748) and [Populating & merging an object collection from Json using a custom iDefaultContractResolver results in shifted/corrupt data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34842336).