# Using AutoMapper, Json.NET, or other library to update parent and children properties with changes that are in a json string

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net, automapper

I have a scenario where I am given a json string that ONLY contains the properties that have been modified for a given parent / children object by the user.

When given this string, I need to load the original object and update it with the changes that are in the json string.

Sample classes

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildObject> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the "original" object.

```
var originalObject = new ParentObject
{
    ID = 1,
    Prop1 = "Prop 1 Original",
    Prop2 = "Prop 2 Original",
    Children = new List<ChildObject>() { new ChildObject {
            ID = 22,
            PropA = "Prop A Original"}
        }
};
```

Here is the Json string with the "modified" object.

```
string modifiedProperties = 
    @"[{
        ""ID"": 1,
        ""Prop1"": ""Prop 1 Changed"",
        ""Children"": [{
            ""ID"": 22,
            ""PropA"": ""Prop A Changed""
        }]
    }]";
```

I must then "update" the "original" object with the properties that changed.

I could use reflection to iterate through the properties of the "original" object and then compare those with the Json string BUT I was wonder if there is some other library like AutoMapper that can do this easier?

Newton Json.NET merge is looking promising.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm

**AutoMapper code -- Mostly working**
This code "ALMOST" works in that it does map the parent and child BUT it fails if the child has a property with the same name as the parent.
AKA the ID field is not mapping on the children.

```
// Configure the mapping
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, ParentObject>());

// Convert the JSon into a dynamic list
var sources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(modifiedProperties);

// Iterate the list of changes
foreach (dynamic source in sources)
{
    // Get the source ID to pull the record from the database
    var sourceID = Convert.ToInt32(source.ID);

    // Simulate a DB call to get the original object
    var destination = originalObject;

    // Map the objects together
    var realDestination = Mapper.Map(source, destination);

    // ** OUTPUT **
    // realDestination.ID = 1 <-- THIS IS CORRECT
    // realDestination.Prop1 = "Prop 1 Changed" <-- THIS IS CORRECT
    // realDestination.Prop2 = "Prop 2 Original" <-- THIS IS CORRECT
    // realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().ID = 0 <-- THIS SHOULD BE 22 NOT 0
    // realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().PropA = "Prop A Changed" <-- THIS IS CORRECT
    // realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().PropB = null <-- THIS IS CORRECT
}
```

I am still working on the json merge option.
Any other suggestion are welcome.

Comment: AutoMapper was a good idea. Saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful. Show the code you used and explain what didn't work.

Comment: Possibly [Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34628916/3744182) would work for you.

Comment: @Equalsk I have added the AutoMapper code, but I'm not sure AutoMapper is the right path because I don't see any documentation on it being able to "merge" just changes.

Comment: Again, you say "DOES NOT WORK" but don't say what actually happens... I don't have the tools handy to write a test but I assume you need something like `CreateMap<Changed, Original>().ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));` which assumes the properties are reference types. As you don't show your classes or example values I have to guess.

Comment: @Equalsk Your code looks promising but when I try it I get a new "empty" parent object. The new object has an ID = 0 and all the properties are null. I am betting I have something coded wrong. Here is the code I borrowed from your example.  `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, ParentObject>().ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)));   var convertedItem = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<dynamic, ParentObject>(jsonDeserilized.FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the link. There is a lot of code in that page and I was hoping that AutoMapper or Json.NET had some "easy" built in methods for this. I'm sure they both do and I just don't know how to use them properly. I'm still digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got both AutoMapper and Json.NET to work.
Here is the code I am using along with test data.

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildObject> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}


// Original object before modifications
var originalObject = new ParentObject
{
    ID = 1,
    Prop1 = "Prop 1 Original",
    Prop2 = "Prop 2 Original",    
    Children = new List<ChildObject>() { new ChildObject {
                ID = 22,
                PropA = "Prop A Original"}
            }
};

// Get the modified properties
string modifiedProperties =
    @"[{
        ""ID"": 1,
        ""Prop1"": ""Prop 1 Changed"",
        ""Children"": [{
            ""ID"": 22,
            ""PropA"": ""Prop A Changed""
        }]
    }]";



/* AUTOMAPPER CODE */

// Convert the JSon into a dynamic list for AUTOMAPPER
var mapperSources = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(modifiedProperties);

// Initialize mapper
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { });

// Iterate the list of changes for AUTOMAPPER
foreach (dynamic source in mapperSources)
{
    // Get the source ID to pull the record from the database
    var sourceID = Convert.ToInt32(source.ID);

    // Simulate a DB call to get the original object
    var destination = originalObject;

    // Map the objects together
    var realDestination = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, destination);
}


/* JSON.NET CODE */

// Convert the JSon into a dynamic list for JSON.NET
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray sources = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(modifiedProperties);

// Iterate the list of changes for JSON.NET
foreach (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject source in sources)
{
    // Get the source ID to pull the record from the database
    var sourceID = Convert.ToInt32(source["ID"]);

    // Simulate a DB call to get the original object
    var destination = originalObject;

    // convert the object into a JObject for merge
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject tempDestination = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(destination);

    // Map the objects together
    tempDestination.Merge(source, new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonMergeSettings
    {
        // Using merge
        MergeArrayHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.MergeArrayHandling.Merge
    });

    var realDestination = tempDestination.ToObject<ParentObject>();
}


/* EXPECTED OUTPUT
    realDestination.ID = 1
    realDestination.Prop1 = "Prop 1 Changed"
    realDestination.Prop2 = "Prop 2 Original"
    realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().ID = 22
    realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().PropA = "Prop A Changed"
    realDestination.Children.FirstOrDefault().PropB = null
*/
```

I ran a .NET Stopwatch and here are the "performance" results as best I know how to measure.
If anyone notices an error in my test code please let me know.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
{
    sw.Restart();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        /* MAPPING CODE HERE */
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed = {0}", sw.Elapsed);
}

/* STOPWATCH RESULTS 
    Elapsed AUTOMAPPER = 00:00:16.5727406
    Elapsed AUTOMAPPER = 00:00:16.8015508
    Elapsed AUTOMAPPER = 00:00:14.6642556
    Elapsed AUTOMAPPER = 00:00:13.9644693

    Elapsed JSON.NET = 00:00:18.8097409
    Elapsed JSON.NET = 00:00:17.6313278
    Elapsed JSON.NET = 00:00:18.6343426
    Elapsed JSON.NET = 00:00:18.8855448
*/
```