# Merge object arrays results in duplicates using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, array-merge

I am trying to merge two JObjects using Newtonsoft.

Here are the models.

```C#
    public class Users
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role
    {
        public int roleId { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
    }
```

I created a user object with some sample data as below:

```C#
//create a sample user
Users user = new Users()
{
    userId = 1,
    name = "Harsh",
    roles = new List<Role>()
    {
        new Role()
        {
            roleId = 1,
            role = "Admin"
        },
        new Role()
        {
            roleId = 2,
            role = "Guest"
        },
        new Role()
        {
            roleId = 3,
            role = "OpUser"
        }
    }
};

//try to update role 3 to PartsUser and add a new role 4 - Manager
var userUpdate = new Users()
{
    userId = 1,
    roles = new List<Role>() 
    {
        new Role()
        {
            roleId = 3,
            role = "PartsUser"
        },
        new Role()
        {
            roleId = 4,
            role = "Manager"
        }
    }
};
```

Now I am trying to merge `userUpdate` to `user` object.

```C#
JObject dest = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

JObject source = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userUpdate));

dest.Merge(source, new JsonMergeSettings() { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union });
```

My expectation was to have a user object with role 3 changed to PartsUser and a new role 4 added for the user.

However, the code results into this:

```json
{
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Harsh",
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleId": 1,
            "role": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "roleId": 2,
            "role": "Guest"
        },
        {
            "roleId": 3,
            "role": "OpUser"
        },
        {
            "roleId": 3,
            "role": "PartsUser"
        },
        {
            "roleId": 4,
            "role": "Manager"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to avoid the duplicate of role 3 but can't seem to find a way to do it. I have tried other `MergeArrayHandling` options but none seem to work. Anybody faced this issue?

Comment: I believe `MergeArrayHandling.Union` checks for items being perfect duplicates, in the sense of `JToken.DeepEquals()`.  But your two `"roleId": 3` objects are not perfect duplicates, their `"role"` value differs.  You would need to set up some merge logic that understands that `"roleId"` is a primary key, but there's no functionality to do that built in.

Comment: Possibly usefully related: [Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34628916/3744182).

Comment: Thank you for moving your question here.

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom Equality Comparer for `Role` based on `roleId` and somehow get the Merge method to utilize that?