# Merge two JSON array in C# where second JSON value override specific matching key/value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have two JSON array with inner json array

```json
[
   {
      "name":"a",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":1
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":1
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

second

```json
[
   {
      "name":"a",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":11
         },
         {
            "first":3,
            "second":22
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"c",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":1
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to merge them having the output like this

```json
[
   {
      "name":"a",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":11
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         },
         {
            "first":3,
            "second":22
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":1
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"c",
      "innerArray":[
         {
            "first":1,
            "second":1
         },
         {
            "first":2,
            "second":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried parsing it to a `JArray` and then apply `Merge` but Whenever I am trying to merge them the result is simply replacing the old value with new one.

```
 jsonarr1.Merge(jasonarr2, new JsonMergeSettings{
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union,
            });
```

But I want to replace same key based items and add missing values from second array in above example please see array with name `a`, its `innerArray` have replace value of Key 1 and also added new key 3 where Key 2 is intact

Comment: Does [Json.Net PopulateObject - update list elements based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638748/3744182) answer your question?  You would need to make a c# data model corresponding to your JSON to make that answer work for you.

Comment: Thank you @dbc let me review and confirm

Comment: Please share with us that code as well which does not produce the expected output.

Comment: Added above which I was trying using merge

Comment: Is this, by any chance, to configure Ocelot and make per-environment overrides?  If yes, I started a few days ago a nuget package that re-arranges the Ocelot route configuration to a version that is overridable.  My approach was different to yours, though.  In any case, it is [wj.Ocelot.Configuration](https://github.com/WJSoftware/wj.Ocelot.Configuration).  If your case is not Ocelot, this won't help, as I did not make any attempt at logic to override individual values of individual objects at the array element level.